# Is the Bondi Radius the Same as the Schwarzschild radius?

Tags: black-hole

$$2MG/c^2$$

This is the expression for both, but some authors use one name and it has confused me. Is there any distinction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bondi radius is $2MG/s^2$ where M is the mass, G is the gravitational constant and $s$ is the speed of *sound* in the medium of the accretion disk.  It represents the boundary between sub-sonic and super-sonic infall of matter into the black hole.

The Schwartzchild radius is $2MG/c^2$ where $c$ is the speed of light and is the radius of the event horizon.

Comment: The OP's error possibly derives from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondi_accretion), which gives the denominator in the expression as $c_{s}^{2}$ where $c_{s}$ is defined as the sound speed in the surrounding medium. A good lesson in paying attention to subscripts ;-)